# Sequelize - query object along with its child

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to query a model along with it child. The child references the parent using belong to. I am trying to findOne parent and include the child in the result.

Following is my user model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const connection = require('../middleware/sql-connection');

const User = connection.define('USR', {
    'ID': { type: Sequelize.BIGINT, primaryKey: true },
    'NM': { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    'EMAIL': { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false, validate: { isEmail: true } },
    'PHONE': { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    'STS': { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false }
});

module.exports = User;
```

Following is my User_TC model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const connection = require('../middleware/sql-connection');
const User = require('./user');

const UserTC = connection.define('USR_TC', {
    'USR_ID': { type: Sequelize.BIGINT, primaryKey: true },
    'TC_ACPT': { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false }
});

UserTC.belongsTo(User, { as: 'User', foreignKey: 'USR_ID' });
module.exports = UserTC;
```

And following is my findOne method:

```
User.findOne({
    include: [
        { model: UserTC, as: 'userTc' }
    ],
    where: { ID: req.userData.id }
})
    .then(user => {
        return res.status(200).json(user);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: err
        });
    });
```

The output throws me an error: `SequelizeEagerLoadingError: USR_TC is not associated to USR!`

Please advice!

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
User.hasMany(user_tc)||User.hasOne(User_tc)
```

to use be able to query usr_tc from User

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out how to achieve this. Following is what I have done:

In my User Model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const connection = require('../middleware/sql-connection');
const UserTC = require('./user-tc');

const User = connection.define('USR', {
    'ID': { type: Sequelize.BIGINT, primaryKey: true },
    'NM': { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    'EMAIL': { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false, validate: { isEmail: true } },
    'PHONE': { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    'STS': { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false }
});
User.hasOne(UserTC, { as: 'userTc', foreignKey: 'USR_ID' });
module.exports = User;
```

in my User_TC model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const connection = require('../middleware/sql-connection');

const UserTC = connection.define('USR_TC', {
    'USR_ID': { type: Sequelize.BIGINT, primaryKey: true, references: 'USR', referencesKey: 'ID' },
    'TC_ACPT': { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false }
});

module.exports = UserTC;
```

and the following findOne method:

```
User.findOne({
    include: [
        { model: UserTC, as: 'userTc' }
    ],
    where: { ID: req.userData.id }
})
    .then(user => {
        return res.status(200).json(user);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: err
        });
    });
```

worked like a charm :) :) and following is my output:

```
{
    "ID": "1",
    "NM": "Tenant-1",
    "EMAIL": "tenant1@gmail.com",
    "PHONE": "1234567890",
    "STS": true,
    "userTc": {
        "USR_ID": "1",
        "TC_ACCPT": false
    }
}
```